# How enable gzip in puma server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip, puma

Please help me. Can the puma server use gzip compression? If yes, how can i configure it?

I try to use config/puma.rb file

something like:

```
gzip on;
```

but nothing helped.

I use: rails 4.0.0, jruby, puma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rack deflater will work with puma

add `use Rack::Deflater` to your config.ru file

Take a look at this question/answer: [Where to insert Rack::Deflater in the rack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236583/where-to-insert-rackdeflater-in-the-rack)

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should use Nginx or Apache for gzip compression. 
You can try [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) link

Puma will only serve the application. Compression, expiration time and other stuff related to the application files are reverse proxy stuff.

Comment: The link here is dead