# Rails 4 Rack::Deflater is not working. Page speed says not gzipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, puma

I have just enabled `Rack::Deflater` in my app. In the headers I can see `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch`. But PageSpeed Insights report that the gzip is not enabled! I use `Nginx` and `Puma` in the server. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related question. We are using rails 4 and ruby 2.2. I tried to enable content compression with Rack deflater like described here(https://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the similar problem.

When I started the suggestion [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater) to inserting `config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater` in `config/application.rb` content was not compressed. Solutions suggested like [`Using config.middleware.insert_before`](http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/163440/how-to-enable-compression-in-ruby-on-rails.aspx) or [`updating config.ru`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616669/1549119) also did not work.

Then I found out that it was not because of any problem with approaches listed above, but it was because, I was using apache/httpd and I had to explicitly enable rack_deflate module as described [here](http://www.brighterlamp.com/2010/10/how-to-enable-mod_deflate-on-apache-to-optimize-page-speed/), and compression started working.

Comment: The link is busted